# communication of 8051 micro controllers C

Tags: c, 8051

I have written a code for communication between 2 micro controllers. Controller 1 sends a number to Controller 2 and goes in 8 bit mode of transmission , if the number is matched, Controller 2 also goes in to 8 bit mode. The code is compiling without errors or warnings but still I am not getting any output on Proteus. I am posting the code:

```
void resetTimer16();


void main()
{
unsigned char i;

i=0;

SCON=0x80;     // 9bit data mode 

TMOD=0x10; // 16bit timer mode

resetTimer16();

TR1=1;

while(1)
{
    if(i==0)
        SBUF=1; // send slave 1 id
    else
        {
            TMOD=0x20;      // move into 8 bit mode

            TH1=-12; // considering a baud rate of 2400 to achieve

            SBUF='U';

            TR1=1;
        }

    while(TI==0)
    {
        if(TF1==1)
        {
            if(i==0)
                resetTimer16();

            TF1=0;
        }
    }

    TI=0;

    i++;        

    if(i==2)
        break;
}

while(1);
 }


void resetTimer16()
{
TH1=0xff;
TL1=0xf4;
}
```

Controller 2 (receiver controller)

```
sbit rs=P2^4;
sbit en=P2^5;

void resetTimer16();
void sendDataLCD(unsigned char dataa);
void sendCommandLCD(unsigned char );
void delay();

void main()
{
unsigned char i,dataa;

i=0;
dataa=0;

SCON=0x90; // enabled receiving and 9bit mode

TMOD=0x20;

            sendCommandLCD(0x38);
        sendCommandLCD(0x0E);
        sendCommandLCD(0x01);
        sendCommandLCD(0x02);

resetTimer16();

while(1)
{
    while(RI==0)
    {
        if(TF1==1)
        {
            if(i==0)
                resetTimer16();

            dataa=1;
            TF1=0;
        }
    }
    RI=0;

    dataa=SBUF;

    if(dataa==1)
    {
        i=1;

        TMOD=0x10; // move into 8bit mode

        TH1=-12;

        TR1=1;
    }

    while(RI==0);

    RI=0;

    dataa=SBUF;


    if(dataa>0) // for testing purpose controler 1 is not sending data =0
    {   
        sendDataLCD(dataa);
    }

}
}

void resetTimer16()
{
TH1=0xff;
TL1=0xf4;
}

 void sendDataLCD(unsigned char dataa)
{
P1=dataa;

rs=1;

en=1;
delay();
en=0;
 }

void sendCommandLCD(unsigned char cmd)
 {
P1=cmd;

rs=0;

en=1;
delay();
en=0;
 }

void delay()
{
unsigned char i,j;

for(i=0;i<255;i++)
    for(j=0;j<255;j++)
    {}
}
```

I have tried to figure out the problem but I failed, so I am seeking help from experts here. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: I am not an 8051 expert so take this with a grain of salt.  But I see both controllers being set to wait for register values to change at points in the code, but I don't see any interrupt controllers being enabled from your comments.  Perhaps 'RI' is an interrupt flag and that works, but I would double check that you don't need some sort of interrupt vector code to get your communications to register correctly.  BTW, what is going on in your debugger?  If no debugger, can you printf debug at all?

Comment: RI and TI automatically get high when data is received and transmitted respectively

Comment: Reading up on your controller...  The first time through your loop in controller 1, it is hitting the If case for setting SBUF to 1 and not falling through into your baud rate stuff or setting TR=1.  But you do prime TR=1 outside your if statement - assuming TR=1 means transmit a byte?  Again, reading up to try and help better...

Comment: http://www.mikroe.com/chapters/view/65/ is pretty dang cool.  Now I can talk your language and help a bit more...

Comment: TR=1 starts timer in 8051

Comment: How is `RI` declared?

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd controller, you are setting TMOD to 0x20 - 8-bit auto-reload, but according to that link, 8-bit mode uses one register for the counter and the other for the destination - meaning that as you count up, you are only giving it 11 - tics before interrupting.  I am not familiar with the timings of this chip, but that seems to be a small value.  Especially considering you are calling it a "resetTimer16", which applies better to the timer mode than the first chip is using.  Is this screwing up your BAUD rate causing bytes not to be received perhaps?

If not, I'll keep digging in a bit...

More digging - is EA, ET1, and ES all enabled - are interrupts, timer1, and serial communications interrupts allowed?

Comment: well both are in 9bit mode first and once cont 1 sends data, it goes in 8bit mode and when cont 2 recieves data very first time, it also moves in 8bit mode

Comment: using something like the multiprocess communication diagram in my web link?